# how to change z-index of datetimepicker on every click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datepicker

I found that datetimepicker default `z-index` is `1`, but for my site I need a `z-index` of `9999`. I have changed the value with jquery in the click handler, however it only works on the first click. Successive clicks don't work. Why is this?

```
<td style="height: 40px;">
    <input type="text" class="datetimepicker" name="sdate" placeholder="Start Date" style="height: 39px; width: 260px;">             
</td>
<td style="height: 40px;">
    <input type="text" class="datetimepicker" name="edate" placeholder="End Date" style="height: 39px; width: 260px;">             
</td>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.datetimepicker').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).datetimepicker({
            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
            showTimezone: false,
            maskInput: true,
            timeFormat: "HH:mm:ss"
        }).focus();
        $('#ui-datepicker-div').css("z-index", 9999); //this is once time work
    });
});
```

Comment: Set the `z-index` value in your CSS

Comment: did you try to set the `z-index` in your css, if it didn't work, it means everytime the `datetimepicker` is opened, it is reset its `z-index` to `1`, try to investigate more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found something fixed code from http://xdsoft.net/ ,I just added destroy function is worked.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.datetimepicker').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).datetimepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        showTimezone: false,
        maskInput: true,
        timeFormat: "HH:mm:ss"
    }).focus();
    $('#ui-datepicker-div').css("z-index", 9999); //this is once time work
    $(this).datetimepicker("destroy");//this is solved my problem
});
```

});

Comment: This is better solved with css, as suggested by Huseyin TUNC(http://stackoverflow.com/a/35863483/299708). No need destroying and re-initializing the widget on every click.

Answer (score 3):

try this in your css file;

```
#ui-datepicker-div {
    z-index: 99999 !important;
}
```